# Clarification on the formalization of tautological consequence

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have a mediocre question.

Just to clarify, if a is a tautological consequence of b, then a ∨ b = b?

It is assumed that a and b are literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are distinct literals, then $a$ cannot be a tautological consequence of $b$!

And if $a$ and $b$ are literals, '$a \lor b = b$' is ill formed.

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are wffs more generally and $\alpha$ is a tautological consequence of  $\beta$, then $\beta \to (\alpha \lor \beta)$ will be a tautology. But $(\alpha \lor \beta) \to \beta$ won't in general be a tautology. So we won't in general have $(\alpha \lor \beta) \equiv \beta$ a tautology -- i.e. we won't have $\vDash (\alpha \lor \beta) \equiv \beta$.

Comment: ok thx but what if theyre atoms?

Comment: Atoms are just one sort of literal (a literal is a naked or negated atom). So the remarks still apply.

Comment: yeah okay I knew that literal is either an atom or the negation of an atom i was just testing u

Comment: ok so this → operator is like a logical operator then so in that way it is a tautology kthx